# how to wrap util method for these scenario

Tags: java

In daily development, I find in some scenario `java` are really inconvenient, e.g.

Example 1

```
    String[] descArray = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};  // coupon desciption
    List<String> codeList = newArrayList("111", null, "333"); // coupon code
    // find those coupon which does not have code
    List<String> nullElementList = newArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < codeList.size(); i++) {
        if (codeList.get(i) == null) {
            nullElementList.add(descArray[i]);
        }
    }
    assertThat(nullElementList).containsExactly("bbb");
```

Example 2

```
    String[] descArray = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}; // coupon description
    List<String> codeList = newArrayList("111", "222", "333"); // coupon code
    Map<String,CouponInfo> descCouponInfoMap = ImmutableMap.of("aaa", new CouponInfo("aaa", 1), "bbb", new CouponInfo("bbb", 2), "ccc", new CouponInfo("ccc", 3)); // desc -- couponInfo

    // to generate new Map<code, count>
    Map<String,Integer> codeCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < codeList.size(); i++) {
        codeCountMap.put(codeList.get(i), descCouponInfoMap.get(descArray[i]).getCount());
    }


    assertThat(codeCountMap).containsExactly(new DefaultMapEntry("111",1),new DefaultMapEntry("222",2),new DefaultMapEntry("333",3));
```

Example 3

```
    List<Foo> fooList = newArrayList(new Foo("aaa"), new Foo("bbb"), new Foo("ccc"));
    List<Bar> barList = newArrayList(new Bar("111"), new Bar("222"), new Bar("333"));
    Map<String,String> descCodeMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fooList.size(); i++) {
        descCodeMap.put(fooList.get(i).getDesc(), barList.get(i).getCode());
    }

    assertThat(descCodeMap).contains(new DefaultMapEntry("aaa","111"),new DefaultMapEntry("bbb","222"),new DefaultMapEntry("ccc","333"));
```

As example 1, could supply below wrapped util method to fulfil it

```
static <T>List<T> findNullElementList(List<T> srcList, List<T> destList)
```

but how about last two? And developer could dynamically specify some property of an object.

Comment: how can `assertThat(nullElementList).containsExactly("bbb")` return `true`?

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: and why do you need to return a list which always contains `null` values?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko it should called nullElementInOtherListAtTheSameIndexList

Comment: @AndyTurner Now our team still use java7, but I feel java8 also could not help in these situations

Comment: @zhuguowei don't you think that "dynamically specify some property of an object" sounds like providing a method reference?

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, I found java8 could help, please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the examples you've given, I suspect you're finding it inconvenient because you're not really using the full potential of OO design.

Take, the following for example:

```
String[] descArray = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};  // coupon desciption
List<String> codeList = newArrayList("111", null, "333"); // coupon code
```

You're storing the properties of 3 objects, in 2 separate arrays.  If you just had a Coupon class you could start to encapsulate some of the behaviour of the object and lead to a much nicer design:

```
for(Coupon coupon : coupons) {
    if(coupon.getDescription() == null) {
        nullElementList.add(coupon);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If use `java8` + `Pair` could help in these situations, see below

first supply a util method to merge two list,

```
<L,R>List<Pair<L,R>> merge(List<L> list1, List<R> list2){
   List<Pair<L,R>> pairList = new ArrayList<>(list1.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        Pair pair = Pair.of(list1.get(i),list2.get(i));
        pairList.add(pair);
    }
    return pairList;
}
```

then 
Example 1

```
    String[] descArray = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};  
    List<String> codeList = newArrayList("111", null, "333"); 
    List<String> nullElementList = merge(asList(descArray), codeList).stream().filter(p -> p.getRight() == null).map(p->p.getLeft()).collect(toList());
    assertThat(nullElementList).containsExactly("bbb");
```

Example 2

```
    String[] descArray = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}; 
    List<String> codeList = newArrayList("111", "222", "333"); 
    Map<String,CouponInfo> descCouponInfoMap = ImmutableMap.of("aaa", new CouponInfo("aaa", 1), "bbb", new CouponInfo("bbb", 2), "ccc", new CouponInfo("ccc", 3)); 

    Map<String, Integer> codeCountMap = merge(asList(descArray), codeList).stream().collect(toMap(p -> p.getRight(), p -> descCouponInfoMap.get(p.getLeft()).getCount()));

    assertThat(codeCountMap).containsExactly(new DefaultMapEntry("111",1),new DefaultMapEntry("222",2),new DefaultMapEntry("333",3));
```

Example 3

```
    List<Foo> fooList = newArrayList(new Foo("aaa"), new Foo("bbb"), new Foo("ccc"));
    List<Bar> barList = newArrayList(new Bar("111"), new Bar("222"), new Bar("333"));
    Map<String, String> descCodeMap = merge(fooList, barList).stream().collect(toMap(p -> p.getLeft().getDesc(), p -> p.getRight().getCode()));
```